# Generate one texture makes shader not work

Tags: opengl, shader, openframeworks

**Shader code:**

```
#extension GL_ARB_texture_rectangle : enable

uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2DRect tex1;
uniform int sampler_type;

void main(void){

    vec4 col;

    if ( sampler_type == 0 ){
        // comment this line - works
        col = texture2D(tex0, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
        //col = texture2D(tex0, gl_TexCoord[0].st/vec2(400, 300));

    }
    else{
        col = texture2DRect(tex1, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    }
    gl_FragColor = col;
}
```

**Main Code:**

```
void drawQuad(int x, int y, int w, int h, float s, float t)
{

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);     glVertex2f(x, y);
    glTexCoord2f(s, 0);     glVertex2f(x+w, y);
    glTexCoord2f(s, t);     glVertex2f(x+w, y+h);
    glTexCoord2f(0, t);     glVertex2f(x, y+h);
    glEnd();

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void setup(){
    shader.setupShaderFromFile(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "test.frag");
    shader.linkProgram();

    img.loadImage("1.jpg");  // DEFAULT loaded in GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE

    GLuint tid;
    glGenTextures(1, &tid);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tid);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, 16*16, 16*16, 0, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);  // init to black...

    // if i comment this 2 line everything work
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void draw(){

    shader.begin();
    shader.setUniform1i("sampler_type", 1);// use GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE
    //shader.setUniformTexture("tex1", img.getTextureReference(), 0);

    //glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    //glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, img.getTextureReference().texData.textureID);
    //glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB);
    shader.setUniform1i("tex1", 0);
    //glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    drawQuad(0, 0, ScrWidth, ScrHeight, ScrWidth, ScrHeight);
    shader.end();

}
```

I dont know why i create another texture will make this shader not works.

There is 2 way to make this shader works.

1. Just use sampler2DRect in my shader. ( comment sampler2D )
2. comment

   glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

Hope that I have described this problem clearly :( 
My platform is WIN7, VS2012, and use openFrameWorks 0.7.4

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. I don't see where `img.getTextureReference().texData.textureID` gets created. If that's in your `setup` routine, then you've got other problems. You also neglect to explain what "not works" means. *What* doesn't work? You only seem to be binding one texture when your shader uses two.

Comment: Where's your `#version` directive?

Comment: sorry about my description. I do this in openFramworks [link](http://www.openframeworks.cc/).

Comment: img.getTextureReference().texData.textureID gets created in img.loadImage("1.jpg"); You can check the code here [link](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/libs/openFrameworks/gl/ofTexture.cpp). Main function is allocate and loadData.  "Not Works" means my shader draw nothing in screen, and "Works" means it will draw a quad-texture of my loaded jpg file. my thoughts is that glTexImage2D()(use GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA) with glTexParameter() will make shader error to load texture(texture2DRect or texture2D), but dont know how to avoid or fixed that.

Comment: i haven't set glsl version in my fragment-shader. so I think is 110

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but this is a mess.

- You are declaring function for drawing quad, but not using it anywhere.
- Everything is drawn within setup(). I am not really sure how is OpenGL implemented in openFrameworks, but dedicated draw() function is there for this reason.
- Missing  #version as genpfault said
- There is no reason why to use direct OpenGL functions, as they wrapped in very easy to use functions.

I don't want to be mean or anything but instead of direct answer, I recommend [this detailed tutorial](http://www.openframeworks.cc/tutorials/graphics/shaders.html), straight from OF guys.